# Incorrect UTC date in MongoDB Compass

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, mongoengine, mongodb-compass

I package my python (`flask`) application with docker. Within my app I'm generating UTC date with `datetime` library using `datetime.utcnow()`.

Unfortunately, when I inspect saved data with `MongoDB Compass` the UTC date is offset two hours (to my local time zone). All my docker containers have time zone set to `Etc/UTC`. Morover, `mongoengine` connection to MongoDB uses `tz_aware=False` and `tzinfo=None`, what prevents on fly date conversions.

Where does the offset come from and how to fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally, after trying to prove myself wrong, and hairless head I found the cause and solution for my problem.

**We are living in the world of illusion** and **what you see is not what you get!!!**. I decided to inspect my data over `mongo shell` client
rather than `MongoDB Compass GUI`. I figure out that data that arrived to database contained correct UTC date. This narrowed all my previous
assumption that there has to be something wrong with my python application, and environment that the application is living in. What left was `MongoDB Compass` itself.
After changing time zone on my machine to a random time zone, and refreshing collection within `MongoDB Compass`, displayed UTC date changed to a date that fits random time zone.

Be aware that `MongoDB Copass` displays whatever is saved in database `Date` field, enlarged about your machine's time zone. Example, if you saved UTC time equivalent to `8:00 am`, 
and your machine's time zone is Europe/Warsaw then `MongoDB Compass` will display `10:00am`.

Comment: Btw. the way how MongoDB Copass displays date is really bad software decision!

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't find this answer in time. Spent hours banging my head against the wall, util figuring out the same thing. Whoever designed this tool shouldn't be let near a keyboard again