# Timezone offset being doubled on my local machine but working fine on UTC server. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, datetime

I'm creating a new `event` on my local machine for my local db and my timezone offset is being duplicated by the server...

When a user of my app creates an `event`, the client-side scripting calculates and *adds* the TZ offset to the input before sending the offset time to the server. You can see this in my `req.body` below after selecting a 9am CST start and 10am CST end (current CST offset is 6hrs).

It looks perfect:

```
req.body  {
  event_name: '9am start from local machine to local db',
  description: 'Testing the timezone offset',
  type: 'mens basketball',
  event_start: '2023-12-13T15:00',  // 09:00 + 06:00 = 15:00
  event_end: '2023-12-13T16:00',    // 10:00 + 06:00 = 16:00
  location_name: 'Home',
  address: '111 West Ave, Austin, TX 78703'
}
```

This is logged from the `createEvent` function on the server side:

```
module.exports.createEvent = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("req.body ", req.body);   // req.body from above

    try {
        // if req.body.address is blank, prevent event.geometry from being set
        const geoData = await geocoder.forwardGeocode({
            query: req.body.address,
            limit: 1
        }).send()
        const event = new Event(req.body);
        if (req.body.address === '') {
            event.geometry.type = 'Point';
            event.geometry.coordinates = [0, 0];
        } else {
            event.geometry = geoData.body.features[0].geometry;
        }

        event.user = req.user._id;

        console.log("event ", event); // here, the start and end times have added 12 hours instead of 6
    
        await event.save();
        req.flash('success', 'Successfully made a new event!');
        res.redirect(`/events/${event._id}/addimage`)
    } catch (e) {
        req.flash('error', e.message);
        res.redirect('new');
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments next to `console.log("event ", event)`, my start and end times have somehow had an ADDITIONAL 6 hours added into the offset bringing the full offset to 12 hours. This can be seen in the `event` object logged in the console:

```
event  {
  event_name: '9am start from local machine to local db',
  description: 'Testing the timezone offset',
  location_name: 'Home',
  address: '111 West Ave, Austin, TX 78703',
  geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ -97.727415, 30.33413 ] },
  event_start: 2023-12-13T21:00:00.000Z,  // 09:00 + 12:00 = 12:00
  event_end: 2023-12-13T22:00:00.000Z,    // 10:00 + 12:00 = 22:00
  type: 'mens basketball',
  activations: [],
  fans: [],
  _id: new ObjectId("6579c977e470980be127375c"),
  image: [],
  created: 2023-12-13T15:10:47.231Z,
  user: new ObjectId("63bd61b0793748758b8ef3fb")
}
```

Another [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098943/incorrect-utc-date-in-mongodb-compass) mentions that MongoDB Compass will sometimes *show* you the adjusted time, misleading the developer. However, I confirmed that both my mongodb compass AND my mongosh terminal shell have the same 12 hour offset as the `event` object in the console.

The craziest part is my production app doesn't have this issue... my start and end times store properly on my MongoDB Atlas and render correctly on the client. The production app is running on a Heroku server set at UTC 00:00.

I'm running mongoose, express, node and ejs in both environments.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Well your code probably is broken in production as well - it's just that when running the app in UTC timezone, doubling the offset of 0 still amounts to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `'2023-12-13T15:00'` is ambiguous. For which timezone is that timestamp meant? When transporting timestamps across system boundaries (e.g. from client to server), always add a [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) to the ISO 8601  format. If you always send your timestamps in UTC, and don't want to change your wire format, at least add the `Z` indicator before passing the string to anything that parses it (as it may otherwise assume its system timezone).

You should send either `'2023-12-13T09:00-06:00'` or `'2023-12-13T15:00Z'`. Both of those will be interpreted correctly by MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi ! That was it. I tried appending a "Z" on my client side but the form was blocking that via formatting error so I added them on the server side before saving the `event`.